# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==221

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

Using the most recent version of python (3.6.2) for Windows, I tried to get pywin32 via pip, but it couldn't be found. What can I change in my requirements.txt to get a solution?

Comment: What could not be found ? pip or pywin32 ? what is your requirements ? please be more precise

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

But I see build 221 is not published on PyPI yet. [The latest version is 220](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32).

EDIT: [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) is an official PyPI package again since some moment. Build `pywin32==228` is the last one with Py2.7 support.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install PyWin32 package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32 first. Downloaded it and ran pip install PATH_TO_WHL_FILE.